# Problems with immutable array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

Recently i started working with D3.js to plot a sunburn graph. The data is provided in JSON. For some design stuff i wanted to swap some items (called childrens in D3 doc).
I know in JS arrays are objects...so something like this:

```
var buffer = myarray[2];
```

is just a reference. Therefore a buffer for swapping has no effect (?).
Thus i invented a second array (childrens_final) in my code which adopt the items while the swapping process. Its just iterating through every item, a second iteration is looking for an item with the same name to set items with same name in a row. Therefore the swap.

```
var childrens = response_data.data.data['children'];
var childrens_final = []
for (var child = 0; child < childrens.length; child++) {
    var category = childrens[child];
    var found = false;
    var i = child+1
    while (!(found) && (i < childrens.length)) {
        if (childrens[i]['name'] == category['name']) {
            var childrens = swapArrayElements(childrens, child+1, i);
            var one = childrens[child];
            var two = childrens[child+1]
            found = true;
            }
            i++;
            }
            if (found) {
                childrens_final.push(one);
                childrens_final.push(two);
                child++;
            }
            else {
                childrens_final.push(childrens[child])
            }
        }
response.data.data['children'] = childrens_final;
return response.data.data;
```

The function swapArrayElements() is just using splice:

```
function swapArrayElements(list, x, y) {
    if (list.length ==1) return list;
    list.splice(x, 1, list.splice(y,1, list[x])[0]);
    return list;
}
```

The problem is that there is still no effect from the swap in the graph. But when logging the childrens_final. There is something like that in the console:

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]
```

The objects are in the right order! But in the array there is still the old order.
Thats actually so basic, but i dont see a solution.

Btw...the code is working under AngularJS.

Comment: Do you have sample data to run this?

Comment: yeah sure...https://jsfiddle.net/b2b6n78e/
sorry...didn't find a better way where to store it

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. It's a D3.js problem. D3 is sorting the data itself. You have to set explicitly:

```
d3.layout.partition.sort(null)
```

Otherwise every pre sorting process has no effect.

Comment: Found this [link for Layouts](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Partition-Layout.md). There is a function .sort() which can be set to null. If not default is descending.
But you're anyway right. The functions is d3.layout.partition.sort().